# Can I take the TB (turberculosis) test for the UK visa outside of my home country?

Tags: visa, uk-visa, medical

I want to know if I can do the TB test for UK visa application outside of my country of origin.  I am currently in Hong Kong but I am from South Korea. Can I take the test in an approved clinic in Hong Kong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In fact some countries don't even have an approved testing clinic, so they HAVE to go elsewhere.

As long as you get it done at one of [the approved locations listed here](https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa/countries-where-you-need-a-tb-test-to-enter-the-uk) you'll be eligible.